# Ionic cant find platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, platform

I'm having problems trying to build my ionic APP with `ionic Cordova build android`.
I already added the platform with `ionic Cordova platform save` but it seems like IONIC isn't able to find the platform

```
>ionic Cordova build android
> Cordova platform add android --save
× Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
> Cordova platform save
√ Running command - done!
[INFO] Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target Cordova

[13:52:18]  build dev started ...
[13:52:19]  clean started ...
[13:52:19]  clean finished in 9 ms
[13:52:19]  copy started ...
[13:52:19]  copy finished in 520 ms
[13:52:19]  deeplinks started ...
[13:52:20]  deeplinks finished in 443 ms
[13:52:20]  transpile started ...
[13:52:44]  transpile finished in 24.69 s
[13:52:44]  preprocess started ...
[13:52:44]  preprocess finished in 3 ms
[13:52:44]  webpack started ...
[13:53:01]  webpack finished in 16.91 s
[13:53:01]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[13:53:08]  sass finished in 7.20 s
[13:53:08]  postprocess started ...
[13:53:08]  postprocess finished in 51 ms
[13:53:08]  lint started ...
[13:53:08]  build dev finished in 50.02 s
> ionic cordova prepare
[WARN] No Cordova platforms listed in config.xml. Nothing to prepare.

       You can save your installed platforms to config.xml with the ionic Cordova platform save command.
```

Here is the config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Fanamex</name>
    <description>Aplicación de fanamex.</description>
    <author email="administracion@ika.mx" href="http://www.ika.mx/">Equipo de desarrollo de ika</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-apprate" spec="^1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^1.11.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.8.15" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="^2.3.1" />
    <plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2" />
    <plugin name="com-sarriaroman-photoviewer" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.1" />
</widget>
```

And here is my IONIC info

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v10.15.3
    npm  : 6.4.1
    OS   : Windows 10
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
ionic cordova platform save
```

> **Error** : No Cordova platforms listed in config.xml. Nothing to prepare. That means your command not executed successfully to add the  android platform.

**Manage Cordova platform targets**

```
ionic cordova platform [<action>] [<platform>] [options]
```

**For Example**

**Adding Platform:** The platform that you would like to add (android, ios)

```
 ionic cordova platform add ios
 ionic cordova platform add android
```

**For Removing Platform**

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

then build the platform.

**Alternative Solution:** Add this line to your config.xml and build android platform.

```
<engine name="android" spec="8.0.0" />
```

***'spec' depend on your android platform requirement***

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove platform first and add again
ionic cordova platform rm android
and add again ionic cordova platform add android

Answer (score 0):

you can do

> Remove platform if exist

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```